# How does Validation.Exception in Java work?

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

I am quite new to Java and I am struggeling to understand Exceptions.
In an Excercise I was supposed to implement the Interface "exceptions.excercise.Validator" in the class "ValidatorImpl" and the Method "User#validate".
I am struggeling to understand what exactly is happening in these lines of codes and I would really appreciate it, if somebody could help me :):

I am not sure if you need the whole java project to understand the code but here's what I don't really understand:
*In *User.java*

```
public void validate() throws UserException {
    Validator valid = new ValidatorImpl();

    try {
        valid.validateAge(this.getAge());
        valid.validateEmailWithRuntimeException(this.getEmail());
    } catch (ValidationException e) {
        throw new UserException("age is incorrect", e);
    } catch(ValidationRuntimeException e ) {
        throw new UserException("mail is incorrect", e);
    }
}
```

*In ValidatorImpl.java*:
package exceptions.excercise;

public class ValidatorImpl implements Validator {

```
@Override
public void validateAge(int age) throws ValidationException {

    if ((age < 0) || (age > 120)) {
        throw new ValidationException(age + "not betweeon 0 and 120");
    }
}

@Override
public void validateEmailWithRuntimeException(String email) {

    if (email == null) {
        throw new ValidationRuntimeException("email is null");
    }
    if (!email.contains("@")) {
        throw new ValidationRuntimeException("email must contain @sign");
    }
}
```

}

I know this is quite a lot.
Thank you if you read all of this :)

Comment: ValidationException is your define own exception,it works like the base Exception in java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you have a try-catch block. This will catch exceptions thrown in the try-part and if an exception is found they'll run the catch-block for the type of exception. The methods `valid.validateAge(int)` and `valid.validateEmailWithRuntimeException(String)` both can throw exceptions.
If the age is under 0 or over 120 `validateAge` will throw an `ValidationException`. The try-catch will catch that and will run the first catch-block, which will output a `new UserExeption("age is incorrect")`.
If the age is valid, `validateEmailWithRuntimeException` will be called next.
This works the same way! If the Email is invalid, a `ValidationRuntimeException` will be thrown and catched. In this case, the second catch-block will be called and a `new UserExeption("mail is incorrect")` will be outputted.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: @tryingtoflow if you think an answer answered your question, you can accept it by clicking the checkmark :) See [How does accepting an answer work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)